# Xamarin Android Facebook AppInviteDialog not showing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using the Xamarin.FacebookSdk to display the App Invite Dialog. For iOS everything works great but for Android, nothing displays.

**Update**

It turns out iOS isn't always working. I actually get the following error sometimes:

```
[0:] Invite Failed Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=9 "(null)"
```

I can step through the following code until it gets to the AppInv.Show. However, Show never shows anything. I tried having the Facebook app installed and without it installed.

```
public class FacebookService : IFacebookService
{
    public void InviteFriends(string appLinkUrl, string previewImageUrl)
    {
        if (AppInviteDialog.CanShow())
        {
            var activity = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Activity;
            var content = new AppInviteContent.Builder().SetApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl).SetPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl).Build() as AppInviteContent;
            //AppInviteDialog.Show(activity, content);
            AppInviteDialog AppInv = new AppInviteDialog(activity);
            var callbackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create();

            var invitecallback = new CCallback();                

            AppInv.RegisterCallback(callbackManager, invitecallback);
            AppInv.Show(content); 
        }
    }       
}

public class CCallback : Java.Lang.Object, IFacebookCallback
{        
    public void OnCancel()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Invite was cancelled");
    }

    public void OnError(FacebookException error)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Invite failed {error.Message}");
    }

    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Invite was a success: {result}");
    }
}
```

I added the following to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
........

<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderXXXXXMy App IdXXXX" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:exported="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that AppInviteDialog was deprecated by Facebook.
It sure would have been nice for a more informative error to be displayed.